# Объединение подколлекций в одну коллекцию с помощью Linq

Tags: c#, linq

есть классы

```
public class B{
}

public class A{
  public List<B> ListB = new List<B>();
}
```

есть лист классов `List<A> ListA = new List<A>();`

как с помощью [`Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq(v=vs.111).aspx) методов объединить все `ListB` из листа `ListA` в один массив или лист или любую другую коллекцию `IEnumerable<B>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать функцию [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var listsB = ListA.SelectMany(x=>x.ListB);
```

Или ее query-синтаксис

```
var listsB = from a in ListA
             from b in a.ListB
             select b;
```

Comment: Ещё бы пример кода...

Comment: Спасибо. Видимо пропустил этот метод. Подтвержу через 11 мин.

Comment: @VladD, добавил :-) думал, пока буду ссылку на справку искать кто-нить успеет ответить :-) поэтому быстро плюхнул ответ и пошел за доп информацией :)